# Mongoose MongoDB in Production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a really weird issue where Mongoose will not perform queries against collections outside of the Model definition file when `NODE_ENV=production`, even when connecting to `localhost`.

**db/default.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = {
    connect(url) {
        mongoose.connect(url);
    }
};
```

**app.js**

```
const db = require('./db/default');
db.connect(config.get('mongoDB.uri'));
```

**User.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', schema);

module.exports = User;
```

**test.js**

```
// This file is required by a route
const User = require('./models/User.model');

User.find({})
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

All of this works absolutely fine when `NODE_ENV=dev`, but as soon as `NODE_ENV=production`, the `User.find({})...` doesn't run. No errors, no success, it just doesn't run.

If I log the `User = require('./models/User.model')`, it is a Mongoose object.

If I run the `User.find({})...` code inside the **User.model.js** file whilst in `production`, that also works.

I am utterly befuddled as to why this does not work.

Comment: Don't use mongoose in production. Its better to go with the native mongdb driver as it is fast and more reliable.

Comment: Oh dip, I forgot about this question. Really no longer applies, been out of the role that this applied to for over a year!